# Detect long double overflows on embedded systems

Tags: c++, overflow, long-double

I'm going to use big numbers in C++ code on an embedded system. Luckily the compiler recognizes long doubles.
I can not use standard libraries, boost libraries, gnu math libraries, etc. And the system has not got built-in float math cpu.
Now how can I detect long double overflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's not standard C++, you will have to rely on methods provided by your specific environment. The manufacturer of the embedded system should have documented how it can be done. Ask him.

Comment: There are no specific methods provided. It's a SH3 CPU and the compiler documentation only mentions the range of long doubles but not how to detect their overflows. I don't need interrupts to catch them, checking overflow after each operation is ok for me. I just don't know how??

Comment: The fact that it's a SH3 is important information. You should add that to your question. I could tell you that if the result of an operation on `long double` is too large to be represented, then NaN should be the result and NaN is the only `long double` value for which `value == value` is `false`. But that's just wild guessing because I don't know that specific CPU, nor the compiler you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Your state that you need "big numbers", but this does not necessarily mean that the use of long double is indicated.  In most embedded applications that I know of, long double is chosen for its enhanced precision, i.e. more bits of resolution for fractional numbers, than for its increased range.

You also state your implementation offers little of the usual floating point libraries and/or functionality.  Based on these statements, I would question whether your need fully functional floating-point capabilities.  If your concerns are limited to "big numbers", check to see if your compiler offers a **long long** datatype, which is a 64-bit integer.

If you do need some floating-point capability, you might consider a fixed-point implementation. Assuming a long long, you might choose to represent numbers in a 48.16 format, which will permit numbers of ~2.8x10^14 with 16 bits to the right of decimal.  (If you need an introduction to fixed-point computation, start [here](http://www.biccari.com/docs/Fixed_point_tutorial.pdf).)

Having addressed some of the background issues, let's look at the original question.  If you wish to detect overflow in an unsigned int (which I commonly do in my embedded work), it's sufficient to compare your latest result with the previous one.  For example, my application requires me to periodically inspect a 16-bit counter that is driven by an external clock.  If my current observation is less than the last observation, then I can assume that the 16-bit counter overflowed, and I can take action accordingly.  If you implement your big numbers using a long long integer datatype, you can apply a similar strategy to detect overflow.